# Favicon e áudio não funcionam

Tags: html, html5, html5-audio, favicon

Este é o código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta name="author" content="Tomás Ricardo">
<audio autoplay>
<source src="audio_de_erro.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="audio_de_erro.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="audio_de_erro.wav" type="audio/wav">
Seu navegador não suporta áudio. Atualize ou troque de navegador.
</audio>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../estilo.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../../imagens/favicon.png" type="image/x-png">
<title>Errado</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body class="tela_de_erro">
<h1>errô!</h1><br><a href="javascript:window.history.go(-1)">Voltar</a>
</body>
</html>
```

O mais estranho é que o estilo.css está sendo carregado. Já tentei de tudo, limpar o cache, mudar a ordem dos atributos, mas nada funciona! Alguém sabe o que fazer?
Esse áudio seria o "ERRÔ" do Faustão.

Comment: Para o favicon, tenta tirar o shortcut do seu link rel, deixa apenas rel="icon".
Para o audio, é possível que a página não esteja encontrando o arquivo de audio, tenta fazer um link no meio da página apontando para o arquivo de audio e tenta fazer um download desse arquivo, para ver se não é um problema de acesso / diretórios.

Comment: Cara outra coisa seu html ta muito bagunçado. A tag audio ta dentro do head, coloca no body, tem tag meta aí depois vem tag link depois tag meta denovo.

Comment: Obrigado, Leandro, eu coloquei o `audio` no `body` e o favicon simplesmente carregou! Mas o áudio ainda não tá indo no Chrome, mas funciona no Firefox e IE. Por que não vai no Chrome?